# Is there a way to set timeout (100ms etc) before registering the next mouse click in windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse, mouse-click

So I have this mouse which has developed a problem where a single click sends 2 click notification to the OS. Since these are sent simultaneously, I was thinking if there is a way to set minimum timeout before next click is registered, it will solve the issue without having to buy a new mouse.

Essentially what I mean is, suppose the timeout if 50ms. If two mouse events are sent within 50ms, the second event will be discarded.

Comment: As a workaround, you could switch the `Control Panel` | `Mouse` | `Button` | `Button configuration` settings and check the little box "***Switch primary and secondary buttons***". Essentially this will reverse the left and right clicks so double right click will become the new double clicker. Assuming the right click button on the mouse is not also defective. Maybe you toggle this on and off as-needed when you are doing heavy double click operations. May take some getting used to as well, but it may suffice for the immediate need for a quick workaround to not require hardware replacement.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle thanks for the response! Switching primary/ secondary works I guess. But that's so annoying :( 

Double click speed I feel is more or a accessibility feature which increases the maximum time between the clicks where it will be registered as a double click as opposed to 2 single clicks. That doesn't help at all.

Comment: Yea, you have a defective left click button on that mouse so it's a hardware thing, so sometimes you have to improvise and compromise for the immediate need. I know File Explorer properties to `single click to open an item` but that may be a file explorer only thing. Does anyone have any mouses around when you need them. Meeces or mouses or mice or my!!

Comment: You can try many things to work around it, but the only option that truly works, is to replace the mouse.